# Limit Of a Recursive Sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find the limit of the following sequence :
>   
>   $a_1=0$
>   
>   $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+5}{4}$

I am trying to get some intuition if the sequence is bounded.

 
$a_2=1.25$ and $\frac{a_n^2}{5}+1=\frac{a_n^2+5}{5}\leq\frac{a_n^2+5}{4}$

therefore $\frac{a_n^2}{5}+1\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @Timbuc Why if descending so there is not limit? isn't what I wrote prove it to be increasing ?

Comment: Forget that comment: I was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the sequence converges to a finite limit, say to $\;L\;$ . Using then arithmetic of limits we get

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n^2+5}4=\frac{L^2+5}4\implies L^2-4L+5=0$$

But this quadratic's discriminant is negative and thus no such real $\;L\;$ can exist, thus either the sequence doesn't converge or else it diverges to $\;+\infty\;$ (as it clearly is non-negative)